# Xamarin - Pasar datos entre pages

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hola amigos aquí Ed aprendiendo con todos ustedes, oigan quiero pasar datos entre vistas ... y por lo que leí es muy sencillo pero creo que algo no estoy haciendo bien ..

este es mi code:

```
public void tryme() {

  string x = lbl_kyo.Text;
  try {
    Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(x));
  } catch (Exception) {

    DisplayAlert("", "crist & shit", "ok");
  }

}
```

Y este el controlador de la vista a donde quiero pasarlo

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Page1: ContentPage {
  public Page1(string data) {
    InitializeComponent();
    string Name = data;
    lbl_name.Text = "" + Name;
  }
}
```

al correrlo me tira la exception del try/catch.
Agradesco como siempre su ayuda wise humans :3

esta es la excepción ---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Donde tienes } catch (Exception) { pon (Exception ex) y pon un punto de parada en el DisplayAlert y dinos la excepcion que sale por favor.

Comment: @WFgo no amigo, **Page1** es una vista cualquiera

Comment: NullReferenceException es porque algun valor que quieres usar esta nulo

Comment: Pero pues como podría mandarle algo vacio? mi **lbl_kyo** es un **entry**